# How to tune TCP TIME_WAIT timeout on Solaris?

Tags: networking, solaris

I'm trying to change the TCP TIME_WAIT timeout on Solaris. According to some Google results I need to run this command:

```
ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_time_wait_interval 60000
```

However I get:

```
operation failed: Not owner
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm already running ndd as root. Is there another way to tune TIME_WAIT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps are you running that command on a non global zone with a shared IP interface.

Comment: I think this is probably it. The server is running on Joyent and they probably set up zones.

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions of:

```
# ls -l /dev/tcp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 2009-05-18 11:17 /dev/tcp -> ../devices/pseudo/tcp@0:tcp

# ls -l /devices/pseudo/tcp@0:tcp
crw-rw-rw- 1 root sys 42, 0 2010-06-01 13:34 /devices/pseudo/tcp@0:tcp
```

You can try running it with truss to see where it fails. It's likely a permission issue.

Also compare the output of `ppriv -l` with another system where it works.